# Laravel App initializing slow after a few weeks of deployment

Tags: php, laravel, cdn, laravel-forge

The app initial load is slow (more than 30 seconds) but everything all pages load faster after initial load.

I redeployed it into a new server and it loaded fine. But after a few weeks the load time is back to 30 seconds.

Using Cloudflare free CDN and SSL, Deployed via Forge, Laravel is optimized, DigitalOcean has enough disk space, memory, database seems fine.

To sum it up, I have no clue what's wrong with it.

Comment: You'll need to gather some more information. What part is slow? Is it the webserver? Is it PHP code? Is it the network? When we experience this issue it's with IIS and .NET framework containers which get suspended when not used. PHP should not have the same issue though

Comment: ***1.*** The webserver seems to be fine when running other things. It's a DigitalOcean droplet with lots  of memory, disk space. 

***2.*** PHP Code looks great and non of our other sites seem to be effected. Coded with almost exactly the same components and by the same people.

***3.*** Our network is Gigabit fiber and the speed tests shows its performing fine.

Comment: Do you see any unusual traffic in the logs of your webserver?

Comment: Nope. All logs seem good. Both nginx and laravel logs look good.

Comment: Could there be slowdowns in 3rd party services like databases or caches? Anything at all that could be cold-starting if unused for a while?

Comment: No there are no service slow downs. Also, it gets around 100-200 hits per day so it's not very idle.

Comment: Did you check the server memory usage? I currently have one of my apps eating up all memory after a few weeks. Likely a memory leak which I couldn't track down

Comment: Only 700mb used out of 8Gb

Answer (score 0):

Try to install laravel debugbar and see what it says. There are statistics how long each operation took, this is your best option sice it can depend on so many various things. 
Possibly a lot of database queries ? Or maybe laravel just creating its cache ? There isnt enough information for us to know.

Answer (score 0):

I think that doubt from CDN caching. If you can test without CDN caching you can identify it. Also your site daily updated with several code changes on different pages, It should cache again and again. So please check your site caching process.